# Redirect every subpage to parent page

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

Currently I'm facing some problems with Google which indexed old wordpress pages. Currently I have a new website which doesn't have these url's anymore so I want to redirect them back to the parent page.

The problem i'm facing now for example is the following:

Google shows an url which would look like this:

```
www.website.com/parent-page/some-other-page
```

I want to redirect all the url's after /parent-page/ back to /parent-page/. So if someone would go to

```
www.website.com/parent-page/some-other-page/
```

they will be redirect to

```
www.website.com/parent-page/
```

Currently I have this code but it isn't working:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^parent/.*$ /parent/ [R=301,QSA,L]
```

I can't find anything related on here so I hope somebody can help me here.

Thanks!